# Is there a way to log a stack trace with symbols from a kext on osx?

Tags: macos, iokit, kernel-extension, xnu

I would like to use it to debug kernel drivers but I would try to avoid to add logging to all functions. OSReportWithBacktrace seems to work but I need symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to print symbolicated stack traces directly from a kext. You can get symbolicated *panic logs* by adding `keepsyms=1` to the `boot-args` nvram variable. I suspect the data structures for this have private linkage so you probably can't replicate the symbolicated panic code in your own kext. (It's in `osfmk/i386/AT386/model_dep.c` of the xnu source though if you want to try.)

Your other option is to send the output from `OSReportWithBacktrace` through the `atos` command-line tool. For kext symbols, you'll need to find the kext's load address from `kextstat` and pass that to the `-l` command line argument.

Finally, you can of course use lldb kernel debugging to get a stack trace. If you need to set a breakpoint during early kext load, before you get a chance to do it from the lldb command line, you can insert `__asm__("int $3")` (IIRC) at the point in the code where you want to break into the debugger.